# how to get fade-in effect each time when flag-image is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fadein

I have published a small "international" quotes script showing dutch, englisch, german and french quotes. Every day different quotes are shown. The draft-result (as there is still some work to do) can be seen in the right upper corner of [the following page ...](https://www.aeternus.org/try/)

The code I have used so far, is the following:

```
<style>
.flag { width: 48px; height: 29px; margin-right: 7px; margin-bottom: 10px; cursor: pointer; }
.bild { width: 100%; align: justify !important; margin-bottom: 10px; }

.fade-in {
  animation: fadeIn ease 10s;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn ease 10s;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn ease 10s;
  -o-animation: fadeIn ease 10s;
  -ms-animation: fadeIn ease 10s;
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
}
</style>

<script>
function myFunction1() { document.getElementById("myframe").src = 
"https://www.aeternus.org/linski_spr/view_spr_NL 2020-09-24.php"; }
function myFunction2() { document.getElementById("myframe").src = 
"https://www.aeternus.org/linski_spr/view_spr_EN 2020-09-24.php"; }
function myFunction3() { document.getElementById("myframe").src = 
"https://www.aeternus.org/linski_spr/view_spr_DE 2020-09-24.php"; }
function myFunction4() { document.getElementById("myframe").src = 
"https://www.aeternus.org/linski_spr/view_spr_FR 2020-09-24.php"; }
</script>

<img onclick="myFunction1()" class="flag" src="https://www.aeternus.org/nl.png" />
<img onclick="myFunction2()" class="flag" src="https://www.aeternus.org/uk.png" />
<img onclick="myFunction3()" class="flag" src="https://www.aeternus.org/de.png" />
<img onclick="myFunction4()" class="flag" src="https://www.aeternus.org/fr.png" />

<div class="fade-in" ><iframe id="myframe" width="100%" height="150" 
src="https://www.aeternus.org/linski_spr/view_spr_NL 2020-09-24.php" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" >
```

And a codepen of the same script [can be found here ...](https://codepen.io/piotr-linski/pen/ZEWwLWP)

The moment the page loads, you will see the fade-in effect doing its initial job.
However, when clicking on the other flags afterwards, the text changes immediately without this fade-in.
I would like to have the fade-in effect perform each time one of the flags is clicked.

How can this be done? Any suggestions highly appreciated.

Comment: For the fadein to work you have to change the className for the flag - the fadein is part of the style definition and the animation kicks in when that className is applied to an object.  So, you will have to remove the `fade-in` class and then re-apply it to trigger the animation

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. The following code did the trick. Additional chenges made:

1. I added an extra function to make the script work on pageload as well.
2. I added some extra CSS to get a kind of fade-in in place when clicking on a flag.

   ```
   <style>
   .manquo {
      text-align: center; 
      margin-bottom: 3px;
      font-size: 120%;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #BC401E;
   }
   .stretch { display: flex; }
   .stretch img { flex:1; margin:5px; /* need some space ?*/ }
   .flag { width: 40px; height: 30px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 6px; cursor: pointer; border: 3px solid #5A5A5A; border-radius: 5px; }
   .fade-in {
     animation: fadeIn ease 5s;
     -webkit-animation: fadeIn ease 5s;
     -moz-animation: fadeIn ease 5s;
     -o-animation: fadeIn ease 5s;
     -ms-animation: fadeIn ease 5s;
   }

   @keyframes fadeIn {
     0% {
       opacity:0;
     }
     100% {
       opacity:1;
     }
   }

   @-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
     0% {
       opacity:0;
     }
     100% {
       opacity:1;
     }
   }

   @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
     0% {
       opacity:0;
     }
     100% {
       opacity:1;
     }
   }

   @-o-keyframes fadeIn {
     0% {
       opacity:0;
     }
     100% {
       opacity:1;
     }
   }

   @-ms-keyframes fadeIn {
     0% {
       opacity:0;
     }
     100% {
       opacity:1;
   }
   </style>



   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">

   // this function decides which quote is shown on page load //
   $("document").ready(function() {
         setTimeout(function() {
           $("#img1").trigger('click');
         },5);
       });

   $(function(){
       $('#img1').click(function(){ 
           if(!$('#iframe1').length) {
                   $('#iframeHolder').html('<iframe id="iframe1" class="fade-in" src="https://www.aeternus.org/linski_spr/view_spr_DE 2020-09-24.php" width="100%" height="130" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" ></iframe>');
           }
       });   
   });
   $(function(){
       $('#img2').click(function(){ 
           if(!$('#iframe2').length) {
                   $('#iframeHolder').html('<iframe id="iframe2" class="fade-in" src="https://www.aeternus.org/linski_spr/view_spr_EN 2020-09-24.php" width="100%" height="130" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" ></iframe>');
           }
       });   
   });
   $(function(){
       $('#img3').click(function(){ 
           if(!$('#iframe3').length) {
                   $('#iframeHolder').html('<iframe id="iframe3" class="fade-in" src="https://www.aeternus.org/linski_spr/view_spr_NL 2020-09-24.php" width="100%" height="130" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" ></iframe>');
           }
       });   
   });
   $(function(){
       $('#img4').click(function(){ 
           if(!$('#iframe4').length) {
                   $('#iframeHolder').html('<iframe id="iframe4" class="fade-in" src="https://www.aeternus.org/linski_spr/view_spr_FR 2020-09-24.php" width="100%" height="130" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" ></iframe>');
           }
       });   
   });
   </script>

   <div class="manquo">Management Quotes</div>
   <div class="stretch">
   <img id="img1" class="flag" src="https://www.aeternus.org/M-DE.jpg" />
   <img id="img2" class="flag" src="https://www.aeternus.org/M-UK.jpg" />
   <img id="img3" class="flag" src="https://www.aeternus.org/M-NL.jpg" />
   <img id="img4" class="flag" src="https://www.aeternus.org/M-FR.jpg" />
   </div>
   <div id="iframeHolder"></div>
   ```

A codepen can be found [via this link ...](https://codepen.io/piotr-linski/pen/QWNYZEG)

2020-09-27: An updated codepen: now when clicking multi times on the same flag at each click, a new quote will be shown. [Fiddle can be found here ...](https://codepen.io/piotr-linski/pen/NWNJEvX)

Comment: I'm glad you fixed this. Before I saw your answer, I did attempt this myself. You can find my [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Richardinho/1bxows5g/)

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks a lot for your alternative solution. It is a good example of clean coding ;-). I appreciate your addition of fade-out functionality as well.

Comment: Hi Richard, for some, to me unclear, reason, your code works perfectly in the codepen
but not when integrated in my website. Where my own codepen solution works perfectly in my website as well. Any ideas what this could be and how to solve?

Comment: I've checked it on Chrome, Edge, Safari, Firefox, Iphone and Android and it seems to work. Maybe earlier versions of Internet Explorer might not work but it should do on IE10. It's impossible to tell without seeing your page but most likely is 1. copy and paste error 2. Conflicting class/variable names 3.script running before the html it is operating on. Make sure the script is put at the bottom of the page so that the elements it is trying to access exist at the time it runs.

Comment: I made an additional fiddle, now each flag can be clicked multi-times instead of having to switch between flags. [link](https://codepen.io/piotr-linski/pen/NWNJEvXA)codepen can be found here ...[/link]